# Django runserver log output into a file

Tags: python, django

How to print logs that come from `python manage.py runserver` into a log file (instead of showing inside a console).

This is the example of log that I want to be saved into a log file:

`Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 19, 2015 - 01:37:54
Django version 1.8.5, using settings 'simpatize.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`

Comment: Have you looked into [Pylog](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyLog) at all. I've used it occasionally to fairly good results.

Comment: can you not just direct the output to a file in your shell? `$python manage.py runserver >>django.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Write the log to file `log.txt` in `C:\dev\appName`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler('.\log.txt')
logger.addHandler(fh)
```